# Roslyn SDK cannot locate the nuget package locally

Tags: c#, sonarqube, nuget-package, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am trying to write custom rules in sonar for C#. After doing some research, got something on how to write rules and integrate with sonar. For the reference please look at the post https://stackoverflow.com/a/53889326/6499361.
So basically we have to follow three steps to do so:

1. Use Roslyn to Write a Live Code Analyzer.Building this project will generate a .nupkg file
2. Use the SonarQube Roslyn SDK to generate a custom SonarQube plugin that wraps the Roslyn analyzer.Running this tool will generate a jar. I am using RoslynSDK-2.0
3. Use the generated jar file as a rule in Sonar, which could be integrated to sonar by using it as a plugin

I have written analyzer code which works fine.I have the .nupkg file with me which is generated after building the project.
Now I want to generate a plugin for sonar. So when I run the generator tool by following command:
`RoslynSonarQubePluginGenerator /a:AnalyzerExample.1.0.6971.18074.nupkg`
I get the following error:
 `No packages with the specified id were found: AnalyzerExample.1.0.6971.18074.nupkg`
I have tried putting the .nupkg file at different locations, as mentioned in the following post: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube-roslyn-sdk#configuring-nuget-feeds
I have attached images, when I run Roslyn plugin generator.
[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPd3p.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter you are passing to the *RoslynSonarQubePluginGenerator* isn't quite right.

You just need to pass the id of your NuGet package to the generator, not the full name of the package file e.g.

```
RoslynSonarQubePluginGenerator /a:AnalyzerExample
```

If there are multiple versions of the package, the generator will use the latest released version. If you want to pick a specific version, add a colon and the version to the command line e.g.

```
RoslynSonarQubePluginGenerator /a:AnalyzerExample:1.0.6971.18074
```

Comment: No packages with the specified id were found: PathHardcodeAnalyzer, having as a Nuget package PathHardcodeAnalyzer.1.1.0.nupkg

Comment: @RashmiJain did you ever figure out what the issue was with this?  I am currently having the same issue.